# Возможна ли анимация по Grid.Column?

Tags: wpf, .net

Возник вопрос во время размышления над проектом - а возможно ли сделать анимацию перемещения элемента по ячейкам грида не зная заранее их размера? Дело в том, что мне как раз было нужно перемещать элемент на определенные позиции, а как их лаконично определить (если это вообще возможно) пока не придумал.

Comment: [Animator](https://github.com/PavelTorgashov/Animator). Правда, это WinForms.

Comment: Вам нужно непрерывное движение или дискретное?

Comment: @АндрейNOP, мне нужна анимация движения. Объект сдвигается до определенной точки, а эту точку удобнее всего определить как центр ячейки

Comment: Ну тогда Grid не подойдет. Хотя, конечно, никто не запрещает положить в него Canvas с Grid.ColumnSpan и анимировать фигуру уже в нем